# Public directory stops serving images when hitting a specific route

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

I have default layouts (footer and header) for all the pages of the app:

```
page.default.layout = name.startsWith("Dashboard/") ?
undefined : MainLayout;
```

in my footer it uses the image from public directory, `public/images/`

```
<img src="images/payment.png" class="img-fluid" alt="payment methods" />
```

the image shows for all pages, but not for this route:

```
Route::get('/product/{product_name}', function (Request $request) {
    $product = DB::table('products')->where('name',$request->product_name)->get();
    return Inertia::render('Product/Show',['product' => $product]);
})->name('product');
```

for now, `Product/Show` is just a component with some static content, but when i use this route, for example:

`Hero.Vue`

```
...
<div class="col-md-6 mt-5">
  <swiper
  :effect="'cards'"
  :grabCursor="true"
  :modules="[EffectCards]"
                    >
    <swiper-slide v-for="product in props.products">
      <Link type="button" as="button" :href="route('product', product.name)">
         <img :src="product.imageUrl" alt="" />
      </Link>
   </swiper-slide>
  </swiper>
</div>
...
```

the `Product/Show` component shows up but both images in the header and footer stop showing, it gives error like : `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`, what could be the problem? thanks in advance

Comment: Not sure if it's this simple, but have you tried `<img src="/images/payment.png" class="img-fluid" alt="payment methods" />` instead of `<img src="images/payment.png" class="img-fluid" alt="payment methods" />` ? I assume you might need the leading `/`

Comment: yea, not sure why you are using relative paths for your image src, you should be using a path based off the root as mentioned above or an absolute URL

Comment: @ahmadkharabsheh No problem, I've added the above as the answer too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my original comment, you will need to add the leading `/` to your image path in order to load from the root directory.

Change
`<img src="images/payment.png" class="img-fluid" alt="payment methods" />`
to
`<img src="/images/payment.png" class="img-fluid" alt="payment methods" />`